# Canada open visa for Romanians from December 2017

Tags: immigration

From December 2017 Romanian Citizens don't require Visa
Will they be able to find work and emigrate into Canada?
I'm married to South African man,we have 3kids.
He can't move free like I do .
How can he join us if I decide to move to Canada and not to the UK?

Comment: The only thing changing in December is the visa requirement for Romanian and Bulgarian visitors to Canada; they can apply for an eTA instead. Note that visitors to Canada cannot work there and can stay in Canada for only a limited time; working and immigration requires different paperwork and nothing about that is changing in December. This is different from the UK, whose EU membership​ provides Romanians with certain rights to live and work there. In Canada they have no such rights and need to apply for the privilege.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [When will citizens from Brazil, Bulgaria and Romania be able to apply for an eTA?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1097&top=16):

> On December 1, 2017, the Government of Canada intends to lift the visa requirements for all Romania and Bulgaria citizens. Further information will be available closer to that date.

### What changes?

Today, as a Romanian citizen, you can visit Canada as a tourist by applying for a visitor visa. This requires the usual forms and application fee and photographs and so on, and may take some time to be approved.

From December 1, 2017, if you would like to visit Canada as a tourist then you can apply for an eTA online. This application process is much faster and cheaper (CAD$7).

## What does not change?

If you would like to move to Canada to live and work, the upcoming changes in December will not affect the process. Emigrating to Canada is possible for people of any nationality, but definitely requires a visa and a thorough application process. See [Immigrate to Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/index.asp) for full information.